# why I can't apply git patch when a file uses CRLF?

Tags: git

I noticed that when I have, in my git repository, a file with CRLF line endings, and I try to create and apply a patch which changes this file, it fails.

This is a simple way to reproduce the problem:

```
$ git init
$ echo -en "foo\r\nbar\r\n" > a.txt
$ git add a.txt
$ git commit -m 'first commit'
$ echo -en "abcd\r\n" >> a.txt
$ git commit -a -m 'second commit'
$ git format-patch -1 HEAD
$ git checkout HEAD~
$ git am 0001-second-commit.patch

Applying: second commit
error: patch failed: a.txt:1
error: a.txt: patch does not apply
Patch failed at 0001 second commit
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
```

What causes this problem? How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: use `git am --keep-cr`.

The patch itself, in `0001-second-commit.patch`, says, in effect: *expect the last line to read `bar` plus a carriage return; add after that another line, also with a carriage return*, but the "mail splitting" process that `git am` uses on a mailbox *removes* both carriage returns.  Hence the internal `git apply` step that `git am` runs  at this point effectively goes: *Whoa, wait, hold on a minute!  The original text here doesn't match!  I'd better fail and make the human help out.*

To fix this, tell `git am` to invoke the mail splitting process differently.  By default, [`git mailsplit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mailsplit) treats carriage returns at ends of lines as mistakes made by some email software, and removes them.  The `--keep-cr` option tells `git mailsplit` that no, it's not a mistake: please keep those carriage turns.  This option is also offered by `git am` itself, and `git am` (but not `git mailsplit`) has a configuration knob to turn it *on* by default: `am.keepcr` can be set to `true`.

If you've configured `am.keepcr` to `true` and want to override it temporarily, `git am` has `--no-keep-cr` as well.